# Best way to remove first 6 bytes, and very last byte. Python

Tags: python, byte

I'm simply looking for the best way to take a file, remove the first 6 bytes, and the very last byte, then save it as a .JPG format. (Original file is a .TEC format, used as Cache for Photos.)

Solved and even made it loop to where my file names where "Old (1)" "Old (2)" etc. It was easier to just rename them all this way. as windows will rename in this format automatically. I had 444 files to convert, and this worked great. Now I get to see all the nudes. Win.

```
x = 1
while (x < 445):
   fp = open('Change ('+str(x)+').tec', "rb")
   data = fp.read()
   fp.close()

   fp = open('Changed ('+str(x)+').jpg', "wb")
   fp.write(data[6:-1])
   fp.close()
x = x + 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "best", but probably the easiest way is to just read it all in and slice the string:

```
fp = open(filename, "rb")
data = fp.read()
fp.close()

fp = open(jpegfilename, "wb")
fp.write(data[6:-1])
fp.close()
```

### Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, if your JPEG is very large, reading the whole thing at once could exhaust your memory. Instead, you could read it a bit at a time, like this:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as ifile:
    with open(jpegfilename, "wb") as ofile:
        ifile.read(6)
        prev = None
        while True:
            chunk = ifile.read(4096)
            if chunk:
                if prev:
                    ofile.write(prev)
                prev = chunk
            else:
                break
        if prev:
            ofile.write(prev[:-1])
```

But given that most JPEG's probably aren't going to come anywhere close to exhausting your memory, this is probably way more complicated than you really need.

Comment: It was so simple! Thank you sir! Worked like a charm!

Comment: To go on step further, I got to do this to like 400 TEC files, and editing the script to change the 'filename' for each file will take forever, anyway to automate this process? Like just do the same thing to all TEC files in the same folder? Or any suggestions?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz: Glad you liked it. Please mark the answer as "accepted" if it is satisfactory so other users can benefit from it (and so I can increase my reputation =D).

Comment: If all the filenames have a similar format (like "file1.tec", "file2.tec", etc.), it's easy to create a loop around the python code which sets the `filename` and `jpegfilename` variables correctly to iterate over all the files. If they have different names, you could dump a directory listing to a file, and then edit it so that the listing becomes a python list of strings giving the filenames, and you can iterate over that. Or if you're on a unix/linux machine, you can use a base `for` loop to iterate over all the files in the directory.

Comment: Or just use `glob.glob()` in python to build a list of all the TEC files and iterate over that.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/cWEuAT

Comment: Yes, I renamed them all to basically 'file1.tec' 'file2.tec' etc....
And will experiment with loops. Thank you sir!

Comment: -1 OP just wants to do a simple byte manipulation of the file.  fp.read() will try to read the entire thing into memory, which can fail.

Comment: @CS Can you provide an alternative answer, then? It's not clear to me what you have in mind? Reading/writing in chunks?

Comment: @CS As you can see in my update, doing this by chunks is not exactly "simple byte manipulation". The only way I can see do to this type of manipulation of a file is to get it into memory first. Maybe if you were just modifying some bytes it'd be easier, but having to remove bytes from the beginning and end of the file has me stumped for a simpler way.