# Is it possible to delete the last byte of a bytes in python?

Tags: python

For some reason, I have to remove the last byte of a bytes. For example,

```
teststr = b'\x01\x02\x03'
```

In my case, I have to remove the last byte \x03. I know the strip can do in the python string case, but it doesn't work in the bytes case.

Is there a way to do this? Any information is appreciated.

Comment: `strip` is available on `bytes` objects too, but it's the wrong tool for either `str` or `bytes`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to remove first 6 bytes, and very last byte. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019150/best-way-to-remove-first-6-bytes-and-very-last-byte-python)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this useful information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use slicing:

```
teststr[:-1]
```

is equal to:

```
b'\x01\x02'
```